# Not able to use my own icon images in my free-jqgrid implementation

Tags: free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid version 4.15.6. I have my own icons for `edit`, `save`, `cancel`, `delete` and `add` actions as images. I wish to use these instead of the default ones that comes with free-jqgrid. How can I change the default icons and use my own images?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Maybe you will need to read the docs how to do this.

Comment: @TonyTomov, could you please give me a pointer to the doc location? a link to the page. I tried a lot but didn't find so far!

Comment: Check the github, maybe you will find something.